# Existence of Root for $f^{(10)}(\xi)$, where $f^{(n)}(0)=0=f(1)$ for $n=0,1,...,9$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a function with domain $[0,1]$ such that $f^{(10)}(x)$ exists for all $x\in$ Dom$(f)$.  Also suppose that $0=f(1)=f(0)=f'(0)=...=f^{(9)}(0)$.  Show that there must exist a $\xi$ in $(0,1)$ fuch that $f^{(10)}(\xi)=0$.

I am not sure where to start.  I believe there is the possibility of using the IVT.  Can we make assumptions of the form of the function: It can't be a trig functions or an exponential, right?  I assume this function must be a polynomial whose degree is greater than 10 and has two roots at $0$ and $1$.  But outside of that I'm not sure what else is going to help here.  I know there must be something of the contidition of those nth derivatives being 0.  Can anyone help guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the IVT, but Rolle's Theorem that will do the trick here -- applied repeatedly ten times. First you can apply it to the given function $f(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ to get a point $c_1\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c_1)=0$. Then you apply it to $f'(x)$ on $[0,c_1]$, etc.

Comment: That is an interesting problem.  Thank you for the insight.